# Remove div from authenticity_token in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authenticity-token

How can I remove the div from authenticity_token in Ruby on Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to work around it by using `form_authenticity_token` as I believe this only returns the value that should be stored.

Take a look at [the documentation](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) for more information.